# Unable to find a suitable version for platform

Tags: web-component

I'm installing [the Google Sheets web component](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/), and after pasting:

```
bower install GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets [--save]
```

It said that it didn't recognize [--save], so I typed

```
bower install GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets
```

and now it's asking:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for platform, please choose one:
    1) platform#master which resolved to 1ea9f88521 and is required by core-comp
onent-page#9653654a2e, polymer#a16a41c923
    2) platform#>=0.3.0 <1.0.0 which resolved to 0.3.3 and is required by core-c
omponent-page#0.3.3, polymer#0.3.3, polymer#0.3.3

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json


[?] Answer:
```

So now my question is: what do I do?

Comment: I guess I can type exclamation point 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, you have to put `--save` before the list of arguments of bower packages. Putting `--save` at the end, bower tries to resolve it as bower package (which is why it couldn't find it.)

The reason why it ask you to choose a version is because your bower package has dependencies with a specified version, and another dependency has the same package as dependency but with a different version. Bower can't decide which version of `platform` you want to install. I think it make sense in that case to choose "stable" release which is `0.3.3`, because `master` could be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Just select your choice preceding with !

Example:-

? Answer:: !4

o/p:
bower polymer                      resolution Saved polymer#~0.5.1 as resolution